Is there an easy way to kill all other ssh session by me(user) on the server, but keep the current ssh session through command line?
For example, if I ssh to the server at multiple office computer, how can I conveniently kill those ssh at home when I ssh to the server machine?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Possibly the easiest way is to kill all the sessions using killall sshd and then log back in again.

kill -9 $(pgrep -u$USER sshd | grep -vw $(ps -p$$ -oppid=))
# if necessary change $USER to $(id -u)

To make it convenient put it in a function or alias set by your profile/shrc/etc or a script.

Nice work, well done.

Using kill -1 will still terminate the processes but also give them a chance to tidy up. Generally -9 should be avoided when possible
